# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent Transaction for bulk insertions

Tags: transactions, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a need to insert into multiple tables at the same time, the thought using transaction seems to be the only way out. But eloquent transaction is not working as I expected. Here is my codesnippet.

```
DB::transaction(function(){

try{
            //Create new tenant
            $ewTenant = new Tenant;
            $ewTenant->tenant_name   = $request->input('tenant_name');
            $ewTenant->tenant_url    = $request->input('tenant_url');
            $ewTenant->tenant_email  = $request->input('tenant_email');
            $ewTenant->tenant_phone  = $request->input('tenant_phone');
            $ewTenant->contact_name  = $request->input('contact_name');
            $ewTenant->plan_id       = $request->input('plan_id');
            $ewTenant->save();
            //Create a default administrator group                    
            $newGroup                   = new UserGroup;
            $newGroup->tenant_id        = $ewTenant->id;
            $newGroup->user_group_name  = "Administrator";
            $newGroup->description      = "Default Administrator's Group";
            //Create a Supper admin for the tenant created          
            $newUser                    =  new Users;               
            $newUser->tenant_id         =  $ewTenant->id;
            $newUser->username          =  "Administrator";
            $newUser->password          =  bcrypt('adminPass');
            $newUser->firstname         =  $request->input('tenant_name');
            $newUser->lastname          =  $request->input('tenant_name');
            $newUser->email             =  $request->input('tenant_email');
            $newUser->phone             =  $request->input('tenant_phone');
            $newUser->auth_question1    =  $newUser->input('auth_question1');
            $newUser->auth_answer       =  $newUser->input('auth_answer');
            $newUser->save();

            //Attache a the created user to the administrator group
            $newUserGroupRelationship                   =   new UserGroupRelationship;
            $newUserGroupRelationship->tenant_id        =   $ewTenant->id;
            $newUserGroupRelationship->user_group_id    =   $newGroup->id;
            $newUserGroupRelationship->user_id          =   $newUser->id;
            $newUserGroupRelationship->save();

            //Create Profile for the admin user
            $newAdministartorProfile                =       new Profile;
            $newAdministartorProfile->tenant_id     =       $ewTenant->id;
            $newAdministartorProfile->name          =       "Administrator";
            $newAdministartorProfile->description   =       "Created at Tenant creation";
            $newAdministartorProfile->save();

            //Bind the group to the newly created profile
            $newProfileGroupRelationship                =       new ProfileGroupRelationship;
            $newProfileGroupRelationship->tenant_id     =       $ewTenant->id;
            $newProfileGroupRelationship->group_id      =       $newGroup->id;
            $newProfileGroupRelationship->profile_id    =       $newAdministartorProfile->id;
            $newProfileGroupRelationship->save();

           //Bind the profile to screen for user access     
      return response()->json(["success"=>true,'error'=> '']);
            //Commit transaction
           DB::commit();
            return response()->json(["success"=>true]);
          }
          catch(\Exception $ex)
          {
   DB::rollback();

              return response()->json(["error"=>"cant create tenant at this time","errormessage"=>$ex]);
          }
```

How do I put all these in a single transaction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `$request` as part of closure. Like:

```
DB::transaction(function()use($request){
    // Code goes here to insert and update models.
})
```